# How to delete 2 specific th in a dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to delete 2 specific th depending on which delete button I press

Here is the relevant code :

```html
<!--HTML-->
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Gérer les formules</button>
<div class="form-group content">
<br />
    <button type="button" class="ajout-formule"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter une formule</i></button>
    <div class="panel-body add-formule">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
// Javascript
// add formule
$('body').on('click', '.ajout-formule', function() {

    const $formule = $('<div>').addClass('div-formule');

    const $ligne_formule = $('<div>').addClass('ligne-formule');
    const $btn_formule = $('<th>');
    const $tableau_formule = $('<table class="table" id="formule">');
    const $head_formule = $('<thead>');
    const $tr_formule = $('<tr>');



    $btn_formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn spr-champs"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn nbr-champs" type="button"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn list-champs" type="button"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<input type="number" name="champs" id="champs" class="form-control pull-left" value="0"/>');

    $tr_formule.append('<th><input type="text" name="titre-formule" id="titre-formule" class="form-control pull-left" /></th>');
    $tr_formule.append('<th style="width:16px;padding-bottom: 16px;"><i class="fas fa-equals"></i></th>');
    $tr_formule.append($btn_formule);

    $head_formule.append($tr_formule);
    $tableau_formule.append($head_formule);

    $ligne_formule.append('<label class="panel-heading">Introduisez la formule : </label>');
    $ligne_formule.append($tableau_formule);

    $formule.append($ligne_formule);
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn ajout-champs"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter un champ</i></button>');
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn save-formule"><i class="fas fa-check-square"> Enregistrer</i></button>');
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn del-formule"><i class="fas fa-trash"> Supprimer</i></button>')
    $(this).parent().find('.add-formule').append($formule);
});

// add field
$('body').on('click', '.ajout-champs', function(event) {
    const $operateur = $('<select id="operateur">').addClass('ligne-formule operateur').css({"border-radius": "5px","padding-left":"3px","padding-right":"3px","margin-bottom":"5px"}).prop("name","operateur");
    const $btn_formule = $('<th>');
    const $th_operateur = $('<th>');
    var nb_cols = document.getElementById('formule').rows[0].cells.length;

    $operateur.append('<option value="plus">&#xf067;</option>');
    $operateur.append('<option value="moins">&#xf068;</option>');
    $operateur.append('<option value="fois">&#xf00d;</option>');
    $operateur.append('<option value="divise">&#xf529;</option>');

    $btn_formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn spr-champs"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn nbr-champs" type="button"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn list-champs" type="button"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<input type="number" name="champs" id="champs" class="form-control pull-left" value="0"/>');

    $th_operateur.append($operateur);

    if (nb_cols == 2)
    {
        $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append($btn_formule);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append($th_operateur);
        $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append($btn_formule);
    }
});
// del field
$('body').on('click', '.spr-champs', function(event) {
    var ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;

    $('th', event.delegateTarget).remove(':nth-child(' + ndx + ')');

});
```

This does work as intended which is not what I want

Here is what this does :

- Each time I press the "Delete" button above my field, it only deletes that whole th

Here is what I want :

- Depending on which delete button I press, delete that specific th but also delete the "Operator" th next to it

Here a screen of what I want :

[image: Screen showing what I want]

Here a screen of how to use the snippet :

[image: Screen showing how to use the snippet]

```js
// collapsible
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    });
}

// add formule
$('body').on('click', '.ajout-formule', function() {

    const $formule = $('<div>').addClass('div-formule');

    const $ligne_formule = $('<div>').addClass('ligne-formule');
    const $btn_formule = $('<th>');
    const $tableau_formule = $('<table class="table" id="formule">');
    const $head_formule = $('<thead>');
    const $tr_formule = $('<tr>');



    $btn_formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn spr-champs"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn nbr-champs" type="button"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn list-champs" type="button"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<input type="number" name="champs" id="champs" class="form-control pull-left" value="0"/>');

    $tr_formule.append('<th><input type="text" name="titre-formule" id="titre-formule" class="form-control pull-left" /></th>');
    $tr_formule.append('<th style="width:16px;padding-bottom: 16px;"><i class="fas fa-equals"></i></th>');
    $tr_formule.append($btn_formule);

    $head_formule.append($tr_formule);
    $tableau_formule.append($head_formule);

    $ligne_formule.append('<label class="panel-heading">Introduisez la formule : </label>');
    $ligne_formule.append($tableau_formule);

    $formule.append($ligne_formule);
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn ajout-champs"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter un champ</i></button>');
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn save-formule"><i class="fas fa-check-square"> Enregistrer</i></button>');
    $formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn del-formule"><i class="fas fa-trash"> Supprimer</i></button>')
    $(this).parent().find('.add-formule').append($formule);
});

// add field
$('body').on('click', '.ajout-champs', function(event) {
    const $operateur = $('<select id="operateur">').addClass('ligne-formule operateur').css({"border-radius": "5px","padding-left":"3px","padding-right":"3px","margin-bottom":"5px"}).prop("name","operateur");
    const $btn_formule = $('<th>');
    const $th_operateur = $('<th>');
    var nb_cols = document.getElementById('formule').rows[0].cells.length;

    $operateur.append('<option value="plus">&#xf067;</option>');
    $operateur.append('<option value="moins">&#xf068;</option>');
    $operateur.append('<option value="fois">&#xf00d;</option>');
    $operateur.append('<option value="divise">&#xf529;</option>');

    $btn_formule.append('<button type="button" class="btn spr-champs"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn nbr-champs" type="button"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<button class="btn list-champs" type="button"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></button>');
    $btn_formule.append('<input type="number" name="champs" id="champs" class="form-control pull-left" value="0"/>');

    $th_operateur.append($operateur);

    if (nb_cols == 2)
    {
        $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append($btn_formule);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append($th_operateur);
        $(this).parent().find('.table thead tr').append($btn_formule);
    }
});

// del field
$('body').on('click', '.spr-champs', function(event) {
    var ndx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;

    $('th', event.delegateTarget).remove(':nth-child(' + ndx + ')');

});
```

```css
/* Style the header with a grey background and some padding */
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header, .collapsible {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a, .panel-body button.collapsible {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo, .panel-body button.collapsible {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover, .panel-body button.collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.header a.active {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
}

.header-right {
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header a, .panel-body button.collapsible {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .header-right {
        float: none;
    }
}

.contenuaccueil {
    text-align: center;
    position : absolute;
    width : 100%;
    color : black;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.background
{
    margin-top : 10%;
    margin-bottom : 10%;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.img
{
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    text-align : center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    color     : #A5A5A5;
    font-family    : "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-size    : 15px;
    font-weight    : 400;
    text-transform   : uppercase;
    text-decoration   : none;
    letter-spacing   : 3px;
}

.box
{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.active_tab1
{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.inactive_tab1
{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #333;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.has-error
{
    border-color:#cc0000;
    background-color:#ffff99;
}

/* Styles go here */

.table-content {
    padding: 20px;
}

.form-control {
    width: 90px;
}

/* Style buttons */
.ajout-lig,.ajout-col,.ajout-graph,.ajout-formule,.save-formule,.ajout-champs, .del-formule {
    background-color: DodgerBlue; /* Blue background */
    border: none; /* Remove borders */
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
    font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
    cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.ajout-lig:hover,.ajout-col:hover,.ajout-graph,.ajout-formule,.save-formule,.ajout-champs, .del-formule {
    background-color: RoyalBlue;
}

.graph, .formule {
    display: block;
    margin : 0.75%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}

.add, .add-formule {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.div-graph, .div-formule {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.grad, .axe-x, .axe-y {
    width: 19.7%;
    display : initial;
}

.grad {
    width: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.collapsible {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

#previous_btn_personal_details, #btn_personal_details, .ajout-champs, .save-formule, .del-formule{
    margin-top : 2.5%;
}

.save-formule, .del-formule{
    margin-left:1%;
    float:right;
}

.operateur {
    font-family: FontAwesome, sans-serif;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.operateur::-ms-expand{
    display:none;
}

.add-formule, .div-formule{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.div-formule{
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Innovatech</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/38b99a3f0e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- Titre + Menu -->
<div class="header">
    <a href="index.php" class="logo">Innovatech</a>
    <div class="header-right">
        <a href="index.php">Accueil</a>
        <a class="active" href="ajout.php">Création</a>
        <a href="modif.php">Nouveau</a>
        <a href="help.php">Mode d'emploi</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Contenu du site web -->
<div class="contenu">
    <br />
    <div class="container box">
        <br />
        <h2 align="center">Création d'un nouvel audit</h2><br />
        <?php echo $message; ?>
        <form method="post" id="register_form">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active_tab1" style="border:1px solid #ccc" id="list_login_details">Informations à propos de l'entreprise</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link inactive_tab1" id="list_personal_details" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Grille d'audit</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link inactive_tab1" id="list_contact_details" style="border:1px solid #ccc">Génération des graphiques</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:16px;">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="personal_details">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Grille d'audit</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-content">

                                <button class="ajout-col" type="button" id="ajout-col"><i class="fas fa-columns"> Ajouter une colonne</i></button>
                                <br />
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table" id="grille">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th></th>
                                            <th>
                                                <button class="btn remove-col" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                                                <button class="btn text-col" type="button"><i class="fas fa-sort-alpha-down"></i></button>
                                                <button class="btn nbr-col" type="button"><i class="fas fa-sort-numeric-down"></i></button>
                                                <button class="btn list-col" type="button"><i class="far fa-list-alt"></i></button>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control pull-left">
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <button class="btn remove-row" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <button class="ajout-lig" type="button"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"> Ajouter une ligne</i></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                                <span id="error_grille" class="text-danger"></span>
                                <span id="error_nom_grille" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="collapsible">Gérer les formules</button>
                            <div class="form-group content">
                                <br />
                                <button type="button" class="ajout-formule"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter une formule</i></button>
                                <div class="panel-body add-formule">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div align="center">
                                <button type="button" name="previous_btn_personal_details" id="previous_btn_personal_details" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Précédent</button>
                                <button type="button" name="btn_personal_details" id="btn_personal_details" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Suivant</button>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Le pied de page -->
<footer>
    <p>
        Innovatech <?php echo date("Y");?> - All rights reserved
    </p>
</footer>

<script src="jss/ajout.js"></script>
<script src="jss/gengrille.js"></script>
<script src="jss/gengraph.js"></script>
<script src="jss/genformule.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you use clone instead of creating your html in code.
Then use closest to navigate from the buttons to some container and use find to find the item you need to access

Comment: Simply make the parent row empty on "onclick" of delete button  fist than use this code to populate it again:" $tr_formule.append('<th><input type="text" name="titre-formule" id="titre-formule" class="form-control pull-left" /></th>');
    $tr_formule.append('<th style="width:16px;padding-bottom: 16px;"><i class="fas fa-equals"></i></th>');
  "

Comment: -> mplungjan I dont really know how to do that
-> ainasma That would delete all the row, that's not what I want, check the screen to see an illustration of what I want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution found :

```js
// del field
$('body').on('click', '.spr-champs', function(event) {
    var th_spr = $(this).parent();
    var num_th = th_spr.parent().children(1).index($(this).parent());

    if (num_th == 2)
    {
        if (th_spr.next('th'))
        {
            th_spr.next('th').remove();
        }
        th_spr.remove();
    }
    else
    {
        th_spr.prev('th').remove();
        th_spr.remove();
    }
});
```

1) Found which th it is `var num_th = th_spr.parent().children(1).index($(this).parent());`

2) Do a simple if -> if it's the first button : delete the field and the operator `next` to it, else : delete the field and the operator `before` it

Comment: Why use that complicated jQuery selector to get num_th? An if is also not needed in this use case.

Comment: How would you have done otherwise to get which th it is ? Because if it's the first button (the th n°3 = input text -> = icon -> first number field), you need to delete that field and the operator next to it. Otherwise, you need to delete that specific field and the operator before it

Comment: I would give it a class or use a wrapper

Comment: I do use a wrapper though

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the jQuery variable **$(this)** to select the clicked button. Use  **parent()** to traverse up the DOM. Use **next()** to get the next element or **prev()** to get the previous element starting from that point in the DOM .

I made a simple example to show what I mean:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  // Shows the button that was clicked on
  // console.log($(this));
  
  // Use parent to capture whole div
  var wrapper = $(this).parent();

  // Delete the previous 'deleteme', if no element is found, it does nothing
  wrapper.prev('.deleteMe').remove();

  // Delete first span after wrapper
  wrapper.next('span').remove()
  
  // Delete wrapper
  wrapper.remove();
        
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="1">Button 1</button>
  <p>Things that get deleted on button 1</p>
</div>
<span>Item that also will be deleted on button 1</span>
<p class="deleteMe">Item before that button 1 doesn't have</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="2">Button 2</button>
  <p>Things that get deleted on button 2</p>
</div>
<span>Item that also will be deleted on button 2</span>
```

Comment: This does help a bit, but how to know if I pressed the first delete button or the second one ? Because if I press the first delete button, it does work because of the next, but if I press the second delete button, it should delete that field and the th ```before``` it, not ```after``` it

Comment: Hey, you can use prev() just like next(). I made an edit to my example.

Comment: Thanks, I figured :)